# multiple script tags in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently working on a angularJS application.In my main html (index.html) file, i have about 30 to 35 script tags like

```
<script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/ct-ui-router-extras.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/ui-grid.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/angular-breadcrumb.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/tv4/tv4.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/objectpath/lib/ObjectPath.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/schema-form.js"></script>  <!-- modified hasSuccess method to avoid success display on initial display of form -->
<script src="libs/bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/bootstrap-decorator.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bower_components/schema-form-datetimepicker/schema-form-date-time-picker.js"></script><!-- using this fork to allow for null date values  https://github.com/ngpatel143/angular-schema-form-datetimepicker/commit/aa28025295ba5988bb30f5c4dc26072cf455d9fb   -->
```

Is it possible to have all this script tags defined in another file outside index.html and then include just that one file?

Comment: Yes, that's typically done with server-side scripting languages, but current "best practice" is to concatenate the files into a single minified and otherwise optimized script to include, although that's likely to change with HTTP/2.

Comment: @zzzzBov You can also create a script that dynamically requests the others, this is common in module loaders - that would probably be better for parallel load (and take advantage of HTTP/2) and is doable without server-side scripting. Besides, doesn’t Angular have module loading? that could be a solution in this case.

Comment: @Theraot, Yes, RequireJS and the like can dynamically load additional resources on-demand, however this will have the same [HTTP/1.1 issue of being throttled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/497418), which is why concatenation is the current "best practice". It also helps that concatenation can include other build steps like transpilers (e.x. Babel and Browserify).